# r language support for AWS DynamoDB

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, httr

This is a follow up / updated question to this:

[AWS dynamodb support for "R" programming language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14224919/aws-dynamodb-support-for-r-programming-language)

I am looking for examples or documentation on how to read in a table from DynamoDB into R.

This question pointed me in the right direction:

[R + httr and EC2 api authentication issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13424660/r-httr-and-ec2-api-authentication-issues)

(answered by the great @hadley himself!).

It's ok if I have to use httr and then parse a json response, but I can't even figure out how to format the POST request.

Thanks!

Comment: My company (Analytical Flavor Systems) is now working on an open source package for querying DynamoDB from R. I will post the link here when the package is released.

Comment: any updates to your DynamoDB - R package?

Answer (score 3):

*Repeating my answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43719043/7947081) since someone sent me this page asking a similar question.*

Here's a simplified version of what I'm using for reading data from DynamoDB into R. It relies on the fact that R and Python can exchange data, and a library called [boto](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) in Python makes it really easy to get data from DynamoDB. It would be neat if this was all an R package, but I won't complain given the 25GB of free storage you can get from Amazon.

First, you need a Python script like so named *query_dynamo.py*:

```
import boto3
import time

dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb',
                          aws_access_key_id='<GET ME FROM AWS>',
                          aws_secret_access_key='<ALSO GET ME FROM AWS CONSOLE>',
                          region_name='us-east-1')

table = dynamodb.Table('comment')  ###Your table name in DynamoDB here

response = table.scan()
data = response['Items']

while 'LastEvaluatedKey' in response:
    response = table.scan(ExclusiveStartKey=response['LastEvaluatedKey'])
    data.extend(response['Items'])
```

Then in R you do this. If you're trying this on Windows, you may want to try [rPython-win](https://github.com/cjgb/rPython-win) instead. I did all this on Ubuntu Linux 16.04 LTS.

```
library(rPython)


python.load("query_dynamo.py")
temp = as.data.frame(python.get('data'))
df = as.data.frame(t(temp))
rm(temp)
```

Now you'll have a dataframe called "df" with the contents of whatever you put in DynamoDB.

Comment: Just flagged it.

Answer (score 0):

You could [stream updates](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.html) to your DynamoDB table with a [Lambda function](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.Lambda.BestPracticesWithDynamoDB.html) to [Connect to Redshift](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/connecting-r-with-amazon-redshift/) as you would [connect to a SQL database](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RODBC/vignettes/RODBC.pdf), and then perform the big data analytics you need against Redshift.