# Connecting to DynamoDB using R

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, rjdbc, rpython

I would like to connect to DynamoDB with R. My ultimate goal is to create a Shiny App to display data that is stored at DynamoDB and updated frequently. So I need an efficient way to retrieve it using R.

The following references give an intuition but they do not include a native implementation in R and have not been updated for a long time.

[r language support for AWS DynamoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18936162/r-language-support-for-aws-dynamodb)
[AWS dynamodb support for "R" programming language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14224919/aws-dynamodb-support-for-r-programming-language)
[R + httr and EC2 api authentication issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13424660/r-httr-and-ec2-api-authentication-issues)

As mentioned in the answers above, running Python within R through `rPython` would be an option as there are SDKs for Python such as `boto3`.

Another alternative would be using a JDBC driver through `RJDBC`, which I tried:

```
library(RJDBC)

drv <- JDBC(
  driverClass = "cdata.jdbc.dynamodb.DynamoDBDriver", 
  classPath = "MyInstallationDir\lib\cdata.jdbc.dynamodb.jar", 
  identifier.quote = "'"
)

conn <- dbConnect(
  drv,
  "Access Key=xxx;Secret Key=xxx;Domain=amazonaws.com;Region=OREGON;"
)
```

(Access Key and Secret Key replaced by *xxx*) and I got the error:

> ```
> Error in .verify.JDBC.result(jc, "Unable to connect JDBC to ", url) : 
>   Unable to connect JDBC to Access Key=xxx;Secret 
> Key=xxx;Domain=amazonaws.com;Region=OREGON;
> ```

What would be the best practice in this matter? Is there a working, native solution for R? I would appreciate if anyone could point me in the right direction.

Note: The package `aws.dynamodb` (https://github.com/cloudyr/aws.dynamodb) looks promising but the documentation lacks examples and I could not find any tutorial for it.

Comment: Have you tried the AWS API documentation? Your can interact with Dynamo using simple HTTP calls, a high level SDK for python or R is not a requirement... https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Operations_Amazon_DynamoDB.html

Comment: @RenatoByrro; I tried but found it very painful. I don't have much experience with HTTP calls. You are very welcome to post an example solution below.

Comment: I'm not familiar with R. Connecting to external DBs would be something trivial in Python, and its data science libraries are very powerful. Chances are whatever you're trying to do in R, there's a way to do in Python as well. Isn't it an option for your use case to rely only on Python instead of R?

Comment: R has very powerful tools for relational databases as well but not for NoSQL ones. I ended up benefiting from `boto3` to pull the data into R as I am building a Shiny App.

Comment: You may want to have a peak at the following package: https://github.com/Appsilon/shiny.collections. It would be nice to have something like this available based on a more mature database platform than ReThinkDB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would like to share some updates so that people with the same issue can benefit from this post:

First, I figured out how to use the JDBC driver with a few tweaks:

```
library(DBI)
library(RJDBC)

drv <- JDBC(
  driverClass = "cdata.jdbc.dynamodb.DynamoDBDriver", 
  classPath = "/Applications/CData/CData JDBC Driver for DynamoDB 2018/lib/cdata.jdbc.dynamodb.jar", 
  identifier.quote = "'"
)

conn <- dbConnect(
  drv, 
  url = 'jdbc:dynamodb: Access Key=xxx; SecretKey=xxx; Domain=amazonaws.com; Region=OREGON;'
)

dbListTables(conn)
```

Second, I realized that `reticulate` makes it very convenient (even more than `rPython`) to run Python code inside R and ended up using *reticulated* `boto3` to get data from DynamoDB into R. You can refer to the following documentations for additional info:
[`reticulate`](https://github.com/rstudio/reticulate)
[`boto3` - DynamoDB](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html)

Last, I heard that RStudio is planning to build a NoSQL database driver (which would be compatible with `DBI`, `dbplyr`, `pool` etc.) but probably it won't be available sometime soon.

Hope someone will create an R package as comprehensive as `boto3` for AWS as it gets more and more popular.